# Node-main script not executed with Nw-react-script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-webkit

I'm trying to create a Desktop App which is using create-nw-react-app and Sqlite.

Since trying to compile native modules with NW.js is a nightmare, I'm trying to start a server with express before the frontend loads using node-main feature in package.json.

But when calling `nw-react-scripts start`, I found that the node-main script is not executed. If I open a separate terminal running the express server it works.

How can I tell NW to start the server before starting react application?

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ultimo",
  "node-main": "api/server.js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/nw.js": "^0.13.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "better-sqlite3": "^8.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "nw-react-scripts": "4.0.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nw-react-scripts start",
    "build": "nw-react-scripts build",
    "test": "nw-react-scripts test",
    "eject": "nw-react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "nw-react-app",
      "nw-react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "main": "index.html",
  "nwBuilder": {
    "//": "https://github.com/nwjs-community/nw-builder",
    "platforms": [
      "osx64",
      "win32",
      "win64"
    ],
    "version": "latest",
    "flavor": "normal",
    "buildDir": "./build",
    "cacheDir": "./cache",
    "macIcns": "./src/logo.icns"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "wait-on": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried to modify to script start into `concurrently \"node api/server.js\" \"nw-react-scripts start\"` and it works, but it's only for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information. This works just fine with NW.js 0.71.0:

**package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "main": "index.html",
  "node-main": "node-main.js",
}
```

***node-main.js***:

```js
console.log('hello world');
```

***index.html***:

```html
Test
```

Run the app, inspect background page, note that it shows "hello world" in the console. If yours doesn't work, there's a bug in `api/server.js`.

Edit: This could be caused by `nw-react-scripts`. Since `create-nw-react-app` doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, you may want to look into other options. You can use the following as an initial template: https://github.com/nwutils/nw-react-example

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried to download the repository you suggested but it doesn't even start. The server file works properly if started separately with the command `node api/server.js`

Comment: I'm wondering....Can I develop my app as a full stack application using traditional express node server and React, and than only after building the react frontend call NW.js to pack all the files and the server in one simple application? It could be easier I think.

Comment: The `nw-react-example` example works perfectly for me, but you really should spend time learning exactly how NW.js works before picking *any* of the packaging tools/scripts/templates.

NW.js is Chromium + Node.js. It's really that simple. Yes, you can spin up a local webserver using the Node.js portion of it and display content from that server in the Chromium portion. The sky is the limit once you understand the Node and Browser contexts in NW.js.